# java.util.Map, melhor implementação considerando apenas get(Object key)

Tags: java

Gostaria de saber qual classe que implemente `java.util.Map` contém o `get(Object key)` mais rápido.

O intuito é fazer um mini cache de dados, o volume de informação será de aproximadamente 2 a 10 mil registros.

`Map<Integer, Funcionario> mapUsuarios = new ???<>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolver o meu problema efetuei um teste com algumas implementações de Map, depois de populados de maneira idêntica com 1400 objetos executei.

```
speedTeste(hashMap, "hashMap");
speedTeste(treeMap, "treeMap");
speedTeste(concurrentHashMap, "concurrentHashMap");

public static void speedTeste(Map map, String type) {

System.out.println("teste velocidade mapa: " + type);
    int count = 0;
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (count++ < 10000000) {
        map.get(1);
    }
    System.out.println("\t " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));

}
```

---

Resultados:

- teste velocidade mapa: HashMap **144**
- teste velocidade mapa: TreeMap **559**
- teste velocidade mapa: ConcurrentHashMap **207**

---

Ou seja, mesmo o TreeMap tendo organizado as chaves neste contexto ele é muito mais lento que o HashMap para obter o valor.

Answer (score 10):

Muito provavelmente `HashMap`, cuja implementação é a mais simples dentre as  alternativas disponíveis: uma simples [tabela de espalhamento](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabela_de_dispers%C3%A3o) não-sincronizada, não-concorrente, não-ordenada (no sentido de não haver garantia na ordem em que seu *iterator* retorna elementos) e não-navegável (no sentido de `NavigableMap`).

A documentação sugere uma otimização na hora de instanciar o `HashMap`:

> This implementation provides constant-time performance for the basic
>   operations (get and put), assuming the hash function disperses the
>   elements properly among the buckets. Iteration over collection views
>   requires time proportional to the "capacity" of the HashMap instance
>   (the number of buckets) plus its size (the number of key-value
>   mappings). Thus, it's very important not to set the initial capacity
>   too high (or the load factor too low) if iteration performance is
>   important.
>
> An instance of HashMap has two parameters that affect its performance:
>   initial capacity and load factor. The capacity is the number of
>   buckets in the hash table, and the initial capacity is simply the
>   capacity at the time the hash table is created. The load factor is a
>   measure of how full the hash table is allowed to get before its
>   capacity is automatically increased. When the number of entries in the
>   hash table exceeds the product of the load factor and the current
>   capacity, the hash table is rehashed (that is, internal data
>   structures are rebuilt) so that the hash table has approximately twice
>   the number of buckets.
>
> As a general rule, the default load factor (.75) offers a good
>   tradeoff between time and space costs. Higher values decrease the
>   space overhead but increase the lookup cost (reflected in most of the
>   operations of the HashMap class, including get and put). The expected
>   number of entries in the map and its load factor should be taken into
>   account when setting its initial capacity, so as to minimize the
>   number of rehash operations. If the initial capacity is greater than
>   the maximum number of entries divided by the load factor, no rehash
>   operations will ever occur.

A ideia é que, havendo memória disponível, se evite custosos processos de *rehash* adotando uma capacidade inicial maior que o quociente entre o número esperado de entradas e o *load factor*. No seu caso que é de 2 a 10 mil elementos, portanto, seria bom instanciar o `HashMap` com uma capacidade inicial da ordem de 2667 a 13334, já que o *load factor* padrão e recomendado é 0.75.

Note que se for em **Android**, vale a pena conhecer a classe `android.util.SparseArray`, que é uma implementação mais eficiente que um `HashMap` para uso com chaves do tipo inteiro.

Answer (score 7):

Depende da forma como você vai popular e quem vai acessar os dados os dados.

Se os dados forem pré-carregados antes do uso ou pelo menos houver somente uma thread acessando o mapa, então o `HashMap` resolve o problema e podemos considerar a resposta do Piovezan como "canônica".

Entretanto, se a ideia é popular o cache sob demanda, isto é, adiciona valores apenas quando ocorre o primeiro acesso aos mesmos, e o acesso é concorrente, como numa aplicação web onde mais de uma requisição pode tentar ler e gravar o cache ao mesmo tempo, então o cenário é completamente diferente.

No segundo cenário, é esperado que o `HashMap` cause problemas, podendo, entretanto, ser substituído por implementações concorrentes como o [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).

Se o cache pode ser pré-carregado e o seu conteúdo é relativamente imutável ao longo do tempo, considere também usar um mapa imutável. Para isso, basta usar o método estático [`Collections.unmodifiableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap-java.util.Map-) para criar um *wrapper* no seu mapa original e assim evitar problemas de acesso concorrente.

Comment: Ótimo comentário, o segundo cenário se enquadra perfeitamente na situação, vou efetuar testes com os Maps comentados e mais alguns como o `TreeMap` e postar os resultados!